# Background Videos HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, playlist

I want to create a background with differents videos, when the user refresh the page change to other video.

Now i have this, maybe with javascript i can do it but i don't know how.

```
   <video loop="loop" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="" poster="/templates/smartone/images/video/fondo.jpg" id="bgvid">
<source src="/templates/smartone/images/video/fondo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
<source src="/templates/smartone/images/video/fondo1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Do you just want to start with a random video on page load or do you want to go to the next video when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Hi Peter, start with a random video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you'll want to run the function at pageload (wrap it in document.ready).

You will want a srcsList array which will hold all your video sources (don't include the file extension).

You want to select a random number limited by the number of sources you have.

Finally you will update the src for your mp4 and webm sources so they reference the new random src.

```
var srcsList = ["/templates/smartone/images/video/fondo1", "/templates/smartone/images/video/fondo2", "/templates/smartone/images/video/fondo3"];
var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * srcsList.length);
var randomSrc = srcsList[randomInt];
$('[type="video/mp4"]').attr('src', randomSrc + '.mp4');
$('[type="video/webm"]').attr('src', randomSrc + '.webm');
```

Comment: I need something in the HTML ? because not works for me

Comment: You would need to include the HTML you have in your question on your page. Take a look at @Kaiido's response it has an implementation example that can pretty much be dropped into your page.

Answer (score 1):

As @zmehboob said, you will have to make a list of videos to pick one randomly.

For this purpose, I'm using an `object` that contains the different available types for creating `source` elements, then I pick a random one for src before iterating through its extensions for `source`elements.

Here is some code (Vanilla):

```js
//  first create the list with extensions as parameters
var videoList = {
    'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer': ['mp4', 'ogv'],
    'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie': ['mp4', 'ogv']
  };

function create_BG_Video() {
  //create the video element and its source
  var el = document.createElement('video');
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  // here is the magic that takes a random key in videoList object
  var k = randomKey(videoList);
  //iterate through each extension to make a new source type
  for (m in videoList[k]) {
    source.src = k + '.' + videoList[k][m];
    var type;
    //as ogg video may be with a '.ogv' extension, we have to watch for it      
    (videoList[k][m] == 'ogv') ? type = 'ogg': type = videoList[k][m];
    source.type = "video/" + type;
    el.appendChild(source);
  }
  el.className = 'bg_video';
  el.width = window.innerWidth;
  el.height = window.innerHeight;
  el.setAttribute('autoplay', 'true');
  //Set it as the first element in our body
  document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.childNodes[0]);
}

  // if it is the only used instance, it could be placed at start of the function
var randomKey = function(obj) {
  // Get all the keys in obj (here videoList)
  var k = Object.keys(obj)
  // Here '<< 0' is equivalent to Math.floor()
  return k[k.length * Math.random() << 0];
};

window.onload = create_BG_Video;
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.bg_video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -999;
  background: #000;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 15%;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows. Some pilots get picked and become
  television programs. Some don't, become nothing. She starred in one of the ones that became nothing.</p>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice example! I like your version of the implementation better.