# Responsive video does not fit video-container

Tags: css, html, video, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a site with a responsive intro video with an overlay division with some text and play button.

My video fits well on local server, but when I upload the project, the video just wont scale.

See prototype of site and the problem live: http://instagib.dk/westring-kbh/

- The button has no function at the moment. The problem is the initial video on the site. It wont fit/scale. I'm trying to make a short video play in the background of an container. The play button will be a large video that opens in a lightbox. Just to save the user some bandwitdh

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-overlay">
        <div class="video-overlay-content">
            <p class="velkommen">Velkommen</p>
            <h1 class="index-hero-text">Har du virkelig<br /> brug for et helt<br /> reklame bureau?</h1>
            <button id="play-video-btn" class="play-video-btn">Afspil video</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <video id="index-intro-video" class="index-intro-video" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" poster="img/westring-logo.svg">
        <source src="video/DoorMist-small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width:480px)">
        <source src="video/DoorMist-small.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width:480px)">
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
video-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
    .video-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; 
        z-index: 2;
        color: #fff; 
    }
        .video-overlay-content {
            margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
            width: 90%;
            height: auto;
        }
            .velkommen {
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .index-hero-text {
                font-size: 30px;
                font-size: 8vw;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .play-video-btn {
                width: 60px;
                height: 30px;
                margin-top: 15px;
                background: #ddd;
                z-index: 3;
            }

    .index-intro-video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 1280px;
    }
```

Comment: nothing happens when I click the video button, sorry.

Comment: It has no function at the moment. The problem is the initial video on the site. It wont fit/scale. I'm trying to make a short video play in the background of an container. The play button will be a large video that opens in a lightbox. Just to save the user some bandwitdh.

Comment: I'm still not getting what you mean. No video plays for me. If you want a background video, which is what I think you are talking about, check out this plugin: http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Comment: Don't know if this the problem, but currently the `media="all and (max-width:480px)"`attributes avoid any screen larger than 480px to load the videos. + maybe you'll be interested in that question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/26109462/3702797

Comment: Okay Mike, sorry for not making sense. I'll check your suggestion.

I have removed the media attribute. It still does not fit the video-container. The video just "collapse" and don't set any height.

Please view the site under 1073px browser width

Comment: I basically want a video background like basicagency has :)

Comment: well the bacground video is a fixed size video, not responsive at all. When you click on the `play`button, it will call the lightbox containing an iframe to vimeo with the video width & height set to 100%

Comment: Omg thanks mate! I did not see that basics video was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to my own problem.

I had place a random placeholder image with incorrect dimensions. That resulted in the bugs I tried to describe, which I did not know. Thank you for your time :)

By the way, I'm pretty novice in the rule set of this stack. Is it correct to answer your own question if you found the solution, to let all know that this post does not need further help.

Comment: Yes, always best to post the solution if you found it :)